# Creating a Re-direct Link from all links to a timed page that re-directs again - speed bump

Tags: java, html, css

Sorry in advanced if this is an existing topic, just couldn't locate one similar to my situation.

I have created a page for re-directing external links.

Example:

"Welcome to our business, you've clicked on an external link and will be re-directed to a website not owned by our business in 10 seconds. Please click on the back arrow link to go back, or wait to be re-directed to the external link."

It's supposed to act as a speed bump, but so far I have all external links directing to this page.

I can't figure out how to direct each link from the new page to the external link without creating a single page per external link... I don't want to do this, and I want to make it easier for anyone creating a post on the website so that they just enter about 20 characters, then add the link and it redirects them to a similar mocked page, that in turn moves the viewer to the external link they clicked on.

I also do not know how to make the page wait a few seconds before re-directing the viewer.

How can I do this? Can someone help me please?

Comment: By making the redirect dynamic. **How** are you generating this page? Also, I hate those "speed bumps". It isn't 1996; we know how the internet works now.

Comment: I agree with you completely, but we are required by auditors to add this. 

I just created a page in wordpress, and manually added the links to go to that page in html. I realize it was wasted work now...

Comment: Well does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: How are you generating this page and these links? We're not mind readers. I asked you this last year.

Comment: Elliott I explained that I had previously linked them to another page. Example: Click on www.google.com and it goes to www.google.com/redirect

Either way. I got a solution from a friend of mine. He coded some javascript for me that got the job done. I figured what I explained before was understandable.

Comment: To put it better for you to understand the redirect was like this: <a href="www.google.com/redirect">www.google.com</a>

Comment: Twenty-four people have read your question in the last 8 months; no one has answered. Perhaps you ought to re-figure what is understandable. `<a href="www.google.com/redirect">www.google.com</a>` is a web-link, not a redirect (dynamic or otherwise). Edit your question, include all relevant details and code. Or don't, but don't expect an answer any time soon.